# Installing Composer globally - mv: cannot create regular file

Tags: php, terminal, composer-php

I'm on Ubuntu and I'm trying to install composer globally on my machine.

I have run

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

but when I tried to `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer` I'm getting an error on the terminal `mv: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/composer': Permission denied`.

The permissions are

```
// $ ls -lah /usr/local/bin/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Aug  1 12:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4.0K Aug  1 12:17 ..
```

I did a quick google search but most solutions I found were suggesting to `chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/` or to `sudo mv ...` which are probably not the best solutions.

Which is the best way to fix this properly?

Comment: Running `mv` using `sudo` is fine and probably the best solution for a global installation. Where do you see a problem?

Comment: Yes, I noticed saying this on composer documentation a few minutes after I post this question. Thank you anyway! If you like you can post your answer below so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `mv` using `sudo` is fine and probably the best solution for a global installation. The only thing to keep in mind is that you have to run a self-update with `sudo` too, so probably you want to install composer for your own user after all to be more flexible?

Comment: `you want to install composer for your own user` How can I do this?

Comment: Just place the `composer.phar` into a folder that your user has the proper permissions for (like you've done in the first four steps in your question) and add that folder to your path

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the commands as user (like it seems), there is no way you can install anything in a system directory like `/usr/local/...` without using  `sudo` as you already find out.

Change the permissions of the directory to 777 is a really bad idea.